# How to set background in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I already can achieve to change the backgroundcolor and seletecionBackground. However, there is still a little blue border.

[image]

This the code I'm using to set the background.

```
jComboBox2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
Object child = jComboBox2.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)child;
JList list = popup.getList();
list.setSelectionBackground(Color.RED);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the border of the `CellEditor`'s component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342495/set-background-of-jcombobox-in-swing